# Grab values from input (radio) and print them somewhere out... WITH jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    $('#leftDiv').ready(function(){

        $("form").submit(function () {
            //data structure
            var radios = [];
            //for printing purposes
            var arrayValues = $("#arrayVal");

            //Getting the values
            $("form :radio:checked").each(function() {
                radios = $(this).attr('value');
            });

            //Printing the values
            $.each(radios, function( index, value ){
                arrayValues.append(
                    $(value)
                );
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

HTML "CODE"

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="leftDiv" class="container"> 
<form action="" method="get"> 
    <fieldset>
        <p>Something 0</p>

        <lable>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group0" value="1" >

        <lable>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group0" value="0" >

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <p>Something 1</p>

        <lable>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group1" value="1" >

        <lable>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group1" value="0" >

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <p>Something 2</p>

        <lable>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group2" value="1" >

        <lable>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group2" value="0" >

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>  
        <input type="submit" name="update" class="button" value="Submit"> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Don't know why but can only get the last value from the radio group.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
radios = $(this).attr('value');
```

try

```
radios.push($(this).attr('value'));
```

Comment: lol, Ok edoloughlin works like a charm, well i found out  that this would also work but don't know if there is any difference: ...function(index) radios[index] = $(this).attr('value');

Answer (score 3):

```
$("form :radio:checked").each(function(i) {
    radios[i] = $(this).val();
});
```

Get the value not the attribute.

Comment: Just to clarify `.attr("value")` is the devil and the source of many bugs. never use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be:

```
  //Getting the values
  $("form :radio:checked").each(function() {
      radios.push($(this).attr('value'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting the values, you have this line of JS:

```
radios = $(this).attr('value');
```

Surely you meant something like `radios[radios.length]`? Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("form :radio:checked").each(function() {
                radios = $(this).attr('value');
            });
```

Each iteration through the each is overwriting the value in radios.  That's why once the loop exists you only have the value from the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I think every time you go around in the $("form :radio:checked").each() function you're overwriting the value of radios instead of adding to it.

You've got this:

```
// Getting the values
$("form :radio:checked").each(function() {
  radios = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

...instead of this:

```
// Getting the values
$("form :radio:checked").each(function(i, e) {
  radios[i] = $(e).attr('value');
});
```

...so when the loop finishes you're only left with the final value.